# How to only auto configure the embedded container?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying bootify my app, which is XML configured. I'd love to have an embedded tomcat server that I can just run through the main method.

The simplest way to do it is to bootstrap the app using the existing XML config through `@ImportResource("classpath:app-servlet.xml")`.

I cannot use auto configuration. We have certain circular dependencies that are not trivial to fix at this point.

The problem is that the embedded tomcat server only gets automatically configured if you use `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

Is there a way to only auto configure the embedded server? I tried looking that Spring Boot's sources, namely [EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.java), including extending it and "running" it through my setup, but it only runs the customizers, not the ServletInitializer, therfore I'm getting an error "Root context already initialized".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `@EnableAutoConfiguration` has an `exclude` attribute to exclude unwanted auto configuration. Maybe it could help you

Comment: Thank you very much @NicolasLabrot . That seems to be the way to go indeed! I'm still getting bean initialization issues, due to my "complicated" circular dependencies. It almost seems like the ordering of the component-scan elements is not being respected. I'll keep trying and I'll update this post if I find a solutions. Thanks again